# Unable to create multiple timelines using chronology.sty

Tags: tikz-pgf, errors, environments

I wanted to create a document that contains multiple timelines on one page.  I am using [chronology.sty](http://www.tug.org/texlive/devsrc/Master/texmf-dist/tex/latex/chronology/chronology.sty), which uses TikZ, to accomplish this. However, I get an error when I try to create more than one timeline in a document.  Here's a block that works and it creates a document with a single timeline:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{chronology}
\begin{document}
\begin{chronology}[2]{2000}{2012}{5ex}{\textwidth}
\event{2004}{single event}
\event[2007]{2009}{Multi-year event}
\end{chronology}
\end{document}
```

But now I want to add another timeline underneath the above:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{chronology}
\begin{document}
\begin{chronology}[2]{2000}{2012}{5ex}{\textwidth}
\event{2004}{single event}
\event[2007]{2009}{Multi-year event}
\end{chronology}

\begin{chronology}[2]{2000}{2012}{5ex}{\textwidth}
\event{2002}{single event 2}
\event[2006]{2008}{Multi-year event 2}
\end{chronology}
\end{document}
```

This produces the error:

```
! LaTeX Error: Command \c@step already defined
```

It appears the problem is caused by a counter variable that chronology.sty creates:

```
\newcounter{step}
```

Is the error that every time I create a chronology environment, LaTeX tries to re-define 'step'?  If so, how do I get around this?

**EDIT:**  I made an error copying my code over here.  My first chronology environment IS properly closed, and I still get the error.  Apologies for the typo.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The `chronology` package defines a number of counters, lengths and boxes *within* the `chronology` environment. That means these lengths/boxes already exist after the first use of `\begin{chronology}`...`\end{chronology}`, causing an error when you use it a second time. Removing the offending `\newcounter`, `\newlength` and `\newsavebox` definitions from `\newenvironment{chronology}` in the `.sty` file fixes this:

```
\newcounter{step}\newcounter{stepstart}\newcounter{stepstop}%
\newcounter{yearstart}\newcounter{yearstop}\newcounter{deltayears}%
\newlength{\xstart}\newlength{\xstop}%
\newlength{\unit}\newlength{\timelinewidth}%
\newsavebox{\timelinebox}%
```

Now, compiling your MWE, it produces the correct result without error.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{chronology}
\begin{document}
\begin{chronology}[2]{2000}{2012}{5ex}{\textwidth}
\event{2004}{single event}
\event[2007]{2009}{Multi-year event}
\end{chronology}% Inserted this missing environment \end

\begin{chronology}[2]{2000}{2012}{5ex}{\textwidth}
\event{2002}{single event 2}
\event[2006]{2008}{Multi-year event 2}
\end{chronology}
\end{document}
```

[image]

This error is not fatal for compiling your document. You can skip over (or ignore) these errors, and TeX should still produce the desired output. However, I would suggest contacting the package author and requesting an update my modifying/correcting this behaviour since it is fairly simple. Some commands obey scoping rules; in this case the definition was global. For completeness, here's the new, updated `chronology.sty`:

```
%%
%% This is file `chronology.sty',
%% generated with the docstrip utility.
%%
%% The original source files were:
%%
%% chronology.dtx  (with options: `package')
%% 
%% This is a generated file.
%% 
%% Copyright (C) 2010 by Levi Wiseman
%% 
%% This work may be distributed and/or modified under the
%% conditions of the LaTeX Project Public License, either version 1.3
%% of this license or (at your option) any later version.
%% The latest version of this license is in
%%   http://www.latex-project.org/lppl.txt
%% and version 1.3 or later is part of all distributions of LaTeX
%% version 2005/12/01 or later.
%% 
%% This work has the LPPL maintenance status `maintained'.
%% 
%% The Current Maintainer of this work is Levi Wiseman.
%% 
%% This work consists of the file chronology.dtx and the derived files
%% chronology.ins, chronology.pdf, and chronology.sty.
%% 
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesPackage{chronology}[2010/6/12 v1.0 Horizontal timeline]
\RequirePackage{calc}
\RequirePackage{tikz}
\RequirePackage{ifthen}

% MOVED NEW DEFINITIONS (COUNTERS/LENGTHS/BOXES)
  \newcounter{step}\newcounter{stepstart}\newcounter{stepstop}%
  \newcounter{yearstart}\newcounter{yearstop}\newcounter{deltayears}%
  \newlength{\xstart}\newlength{\xstop}%
  \newlength{\unit}\newlength{\timelinewidth}%
  \newsavebox{\timelinebox}%
\newenvironment{chronology}[5][5]{%
  %\newcounter{step}\newcounter{stepstart}\newcounter{stepstop}%
  %\newcounter{yearstart}\newcounter{yearstop}\newcounter{deltayears}%
  %\newlength{\xstart}\newlength{\xstop}%
  %\newlength{\unit}\newlength{\timelinewidth}%
  \setcounter{step}{#1}%
  \setcounter{yearstart}{#2}\setcounter{yearstop}{#3}%
  \setcounter{deltayears}{\theyearstop-\theyearstart}%
  \setlength{\unit}{#4}%
  \setlength{\timelinewidth}{#5}%
  \pgfmathsetcounter{stepstart}%
    {\theyearstart+\thestep-mod(\theyearstart,\thestep)}%
  \pgfmathsetcounter{stepstop}{\theyearstop-mod(\theyearstop,\thestep)}%
  \addtocounter{step}{\thestepstart}%
  %\newsavebox{\timelinebox}%
  \begin{lrbox}{\timelinebox}%
    \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline={(current bounding box.north)}]%
      \draw [|->] (0,0) -- (\thedeltayears*\unit+\unit, 0);%
      \foreach \x in {1,...,\thedeltayears}%
        \draw[xshift=\x*\unit] (0,-.1\unit) -- (0,.1\unit);%
      \addtocounter{deltayears}{1}%
      \foreach \x in {\thestepstart,\thestep,...,\thestepstop}{%
        \pgfmathsetlength\xstop{(\x-\theyearstart)*\unit}%
        \draw[xshift=\xstop] (0,-.3\unit) -- (0,.3\unit);%
        \node at (\xstop,0) [below=.2\unit] {\x};}}{%
    \end{tikzpicture}%
  \end{lrbox}%
  \raisebox{2ex}{\resizebox{\timelinewidth}{!}{\usebox{\timelinebox}}}}%
\newcommand{\event}[3][e]{%
  \pgfmathsetlength\xstop{(#2-\theyearstart)*\unit}%
  \ifx #1e%
    \draw[fill=black,draw=none,opacity=0.5]%
      (\xstop, 0) circle (.2\unit)%
      node[opacity=1,rotate=45,right=.5\unit] {#3};%
  \else%
    \pgfmathsetlength\xstart{(#1-\theyearstart)*\unit}%
    \draw[fill=black,draw=none,opacity=0.5,rounded corners=.2\unit]%
      (\xstart,-.2\unit) rectangle%
      node[opacity=1,rotate=45,right=.5\unit] {#3} (\xstop,.2\unit);%
  \fi}%
\newcommand{\decimaldate}[3]{(#1-1)/31/12+(#2-1)/12+#3}
\endinput
%%
%% End of file `chronology.sty'.
```

Answer (score 0):

You must have one `\end{chronology}` for each `\begin{chronology}`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{chronology}
\begin{document}

\begin{chronology}[2]{2000}{2012}{5ex}{\textwidth}
\event{2004}{single event}
\event[2007]{2009}{Multi-year event}
\end{chronology}

\begin{chronology}[2]{2000}{2012}{5ex}{\textwidth}
\event{2002}{single event 2}
\event[2006]{2008}{Multi-year event 2}
\end{chronology}

\end{document}
```

I don't have the opportunity to test the code, but I think it will work.