# Creating a timeline with chronology

Tags: chronology

I am trying to create a simple timeline with years underneath the line and some explaining text above each year. I understand that `chronology` is useful for this.

My problem is that when trying out examples from related questions (e.g. [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/161257/how-to-use-chronology-package-to-draw-this-timeline) or [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/109382/chronology-adds-arbitrary-gaps?rq=1)), I always get the error "! Missing number, treated as zero."

A MWE (from the first related question linked to above):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{chronology}
\begin{document}
\begin{chronology}[3]{2011}{2016}{3ex}{\textwidth}
\end{chronology}
\end{document}
```

Which results in:

```
! Missing number, treated as zero. 
to be read again> 
} 
l.4 ...chronology}[3]{2011}{2016}{3ex}{\textwidth}
?
```

I have tried changing some of the values or removing them altogether, but this doesn't seem to help.

Has anyone encountered this problem or does anyone know of a solution? `Chronology` seems to be exactly what I need.

Comment: @LaRiFaRi That produced a tiny timeline without the years.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Removing the `3ex` produces the following output without error:

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{chronology}
\begin{document}
\begin{chronology}[3]{2011}{2016}{\textwidth}
\end{chronology}
\end{document}
```

Comment: That does it! I had tried leaving the curly braces around "3ex" empty, but hadn't tried you solution.

Comment: It is still strange that the code in my MWE does compile for others...

Comment: My only guess is that the package has been updated without changing the version info.  It is very short on documentation...

Answer (score 2):

The package has been changed after [Oct 14 '11](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/31603) (edit: or even [Apr 18 '13](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/109391)) as the counters and lengths have been moved outside the environment definition. I do not know, why the [CTAN](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/chronology) is telling differently. Maybe it was happening both (Werner's post and Levi's fix) at more or less the same time.

However, the actual code does not provide the fixed definition of the `chronology` environment, which can be found [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/109391), too.

Using Werner's and Gonzalo's code, you get the image of [the other post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/161257) you have linked to.

```
% arara: pdflatex

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{chronology}

\renewenvironment{chronology}[5][6]{%
    \setcounter{step}{#1}%
    \setcounter{yearstart}{#2}\setcounter{yearstop}{#3}%
    \setcounter{deltayears}{\theyearstop-\theyearstart}%
    \setlength{\unit}{#4}%
    \setlength{\timelinewidth}{#5}%
    \pgfmathsetcounter{stepstart}%
    {\theyearstart+\thestep-mod(\theyearstart,\thestep)}%
    \pgfmathsetcounter{stepstop}{\theyearstop-mod(\theyearstop,\thestep)}%
    \addtocounter{step}{\thestepstart}%
    \begin{lrbox}{\timelinebox}%
    \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline={(current bounding box.north)}]%
    \draw [|->] (0,0) -- (\thedeltayears*\unit+\unit, 0);%
    \foreach \x in {1,...,\thedeltayears}%
    \draw[xshift=\x*\unit] (0,-.1\unit) -- (0,.1\unit);%
    \addtocounter{deltayears}{1}%
    \foreach \x in {\thestepstart,\thestep,...,\thestepstop}{%
        \pgfmathsetlength\xstop{(\x-\theyearstart)*\unit}%
        \draw[xshift=\xstop] (0,-.3\unit) -- (0,.3\unit);%
        \node at (\xstop,0) [below=.2\unit] {\x};}%
    }
{%
\end{tikzpicture}%
\end{lrbox}%
    \raisebox{2ex}{\resizebox{\timelinewidth}{!}{\usebox{\timelinebox}}}}%

\begin{document}
    \noindent
    \begin{chronology}[3]{2011}{2016}{3ex}{\textwidth}
    \end{chronology}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. That worked in the example, but curiously not when I started adding `/event`s. I still got it to work with the answer I accepted above, but with different problems. I've asked a follow-up [question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/233811/chronology-timeline-problem-with-long-stretches-of-time).

Comment: What should do if I want something like: `100 --- 150 --- 200 ---- 250 --- 300 -----350 --- ...`