# Chronology timeline - problem with long stretches of time

Tags: chronology

This is a follow-up question to [Creating a timeline with chronology](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/233781/creating-a-timeline-with-chronology).

When I use the following to create a timeline:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{chronology}

\begin{document}

\begin{chronology}[5]{1100}{1900}{16cm}[16cm]
\event[1110]{1150}{Historical event A}
\event[1555]{1575}{Historical event B}
\event[1575]{1770}{Historical event C}
\end{chronology}

\end{document}
```

The result is:

[image: Timeline using chronology]

Obviously, this is useless as every single year between 1100 and 1900 is drawn. Ideally, only 1100, 1500, and 1900 (for instance) should be included, in addition to the years concerning the events. Perhaps also tickmarks per 100 or 50 years in between.

How does one make `chronology` only show selected years? I've tried to look it up, but `chronology` [documentation](http://psg.mtu.edu/pub/ctan/macros/latex/contrib/chronology/chronology.pdf) is very limited... (Am I perhaps better of using `tikz`?)

Comment: `chronology` apparently uses `tikz` ;-)

Comment: Sorry, I meant PGF/tikz ;)

Comment: The documentation is ...really limited.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The first optional parameter of `chronology` environment is meant for time  steps, so `5` means every `5th` year, which is too much for the time span of 8 centuries.

Looking into the code reveals that the `2nd` argument is used for the time start and handled over to a `\setcounter`, but this is effectively wrong, so one should start with `1099` instead of `1100`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{chronology}

\begin{document}

\begin{chronology}[100]{1100}{1900}{16cm}[16cm]
\event[1110]{1150}{Historical event A}
\event[1555]{1575}{Historical event B}
\event[1575]{1770}{Historical event C}
\end{chronology}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Great, that works! Although after trying various approaches to make it even clearer, I think I'll have to conclude that `chronology` just isn't right for larger timespans. Things get too crowded.

Comment: @P.deRijke: Yes, but I have not used another one so far.